# Strange file ownership after rsync W7/U14.04

Tags: samba, fstab, rsync

I've set up a small home network with two machines running Ubuntu (14.04 LTS), my W7 workstation and an iMac. So far I've managed to get things going pretty well and yesterday I set out to update my backups. I have a dedicated folder on my W7 machine where I keep all my photos and I wanted to make sure that all files were backed up on my home server. I use Samba to share the folders and set up a cron job with rsync to pull data from W7 to Ubuntu later that night: `rsync -avhP /media/w7photo/ /media/storage/photos`

When I got the email output from cron, I found there had been a few issues:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/media/storage/photos/2014": Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: failed to set times on "/media/storage/photos/2014/2014-01-12": Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: failed to set permissions on "/media/storage/photos/2014/2014-01-12/20140112-0001.nef": Operation not permitted (1)`
```

and about 1000 more files with the same error in various subfolders in the `2014` folder, all from the same time of the year.

The `cron` output ended like this:

```
sent 4.88M bytes  received 189.17K bytes  41.42K bytes/sec
total size is 900.38G  speedup is 177,466.40
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]
```

When listing the contents of the `photos` folder, the `2014` folder and its contents have a different owner and different rights:

```
drwxr-xr-x 24 zarkov users   4096 jan 12  2014 2013/
drwxrwxrwx 23   1001   1001  4096 aug  3 19:43 2014/
drwxr-xr-x 16 zarkov zarkov  4096 jul 28 12:36 2015/
zarkov@server:/media/storage/photos/2014$ ll
total 108
drwxrwxrwx 23   1001   1001  4096 aug  3 19:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 18 zarkov  users  4096 jul  7 20:14 ../
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 sep 26 15:29 2014-01-12/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 maj  3  2014 2014-04-12/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 maj  3  2014 2014-04-13/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 maj  3  2014 2014-04-14/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001 12288 maj  3  2014 2014-04-15/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 maj  3  2014 2014-04-16/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 sep 26 00:23 2014-04-17/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 sep 26 00:24 2014-04-18/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 maj  3  2014 2014-04-19/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 maj  3  2014 2014-04-20/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 sep 26 00:25 2014-04-21/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 maj  3  2014 2014-04-22/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 maj  3  2014 2014-04-23/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 maj  3  2014 2014-04-26/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 maj  3  2014 2014-04-28/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001   1001  4096 maj  3  2014 2014-04-29/
drwxr-xr-x  2 zarkov zarkov  4096 sep 18  2014 2014-08-27/
drwxr-xr-x  2 zarkov zarkov  4096 sep 18  2014 2014-09-18/
drwxr-xr-x  2 zarkov zarkov  4096 okt 26  2014 2014-10-24/
drwxr-xr-x  2 zarkov zarkov 12288 okt 26  2014 2014-10-25/
drwxr-xr-x  2 zarkov zarkov  4096 okt 26  2014 2014-10-26/
```

My `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
# windows share
//windows/photos  /media/w7photo   cifs    guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8   0       0
```

Do I need to add anything to the `fstab` or `rsync` options to make things run more smoothly next time? And most important, can I just run `chown -r zarkov:users /media/storage/photos/2014` to regain file ownership?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `rsync` options but you should be able to `chown` the entire partition recursively or you can just `chown` the directory recursively as you have described without issue because the permissions don't apply to Windows.

```
sudo chown -r zarkov:zarkov /media/storage/photos
```

Once you have used `chown` to correct permission they should *stick* so you shouldn't have to do this again (on that directory). As I said before, you can recursively `chown` the entire directory so that you shouldn't have permission issues with that directory anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I tried chown'ing my `2014/` directory and it seems to work when I run rsync again, I don't get any error messages. I still don't understand what happened and who the `1001`user is?